# Unable to login to Paypal sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

DISCLAIMER: This question is specifically for the Paypal forum.

I have two Sandbox test accounts. parijat_kalia@hotmail.com (PERSONAL) and parijat_kalia-facilitator@hotmail.com (BUSINESS). The second one has the API credentials and I am using the NVP API to test our e-commerce subscription plan

. The response I get is : 
10501: Invalid Configuration This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration. Occurs when the billing agreement is disabled or inactive.

Hence, to activate it, I presume I need to log in with this sandbox account into the sandbox website so as to activate the billing agreement. The steps I follow are pretty basic.

1. Login to developers.paypal.com
2. Click on Applications tab in the horizontal menu
3. Click on Sandbox accounts in the vertical menu
4. Click on the specific accounts 'parijat_kalia-facilitator@hotmail.com' dropdown arrow button.
5. Click on Sandbox site

When i click on sandbox site, it loads in the PERSONAL account in the email i.e 'parijat_kalia@hotmail.com'. I obviously change this and try to login with the business account credentials. However it does not log me in whatsoever.  I have changed the password, literally copy pasted it, but it does not work. Nor does deleting the cookies/clearing the cache and terminating the history help. Also, I am using Chrome, not IE.

Also, I presume this error is with Paypal's sandbox website, since the API call is technically logging me in with the credentials (I infer this since I am getting error 10501).

Can you please tell me what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue similar to that the other day.  I was trying to switch from one developer account to another, but it kept logging me in as the first one.  So, I couldn't use any of the sandbox accounts for the 2nd account.

I circumvented this issue by switching to private browsing mode in chrome (ctrl+shift+N) and logging in that way.

I can't guarantee this will fix your issue because it's not the same as mine, but it might help.

Comment: that's interesting, will give it a shot ...

Comment: Clearing the paypal.com cookies (or switching to private browsing mode where they don't apply) is what solves this issue. Essentially, the old developer.paypal.com cookies are incompatible with the new developer.paypal.com.  A one-time clearing should resolve the issue for you.

Comment: thanks @PrestonAlexander, I did delete the cookies, pretty much cleared history from the beginning of time in my chrome browser, but no the issue still persists...if you have any other clues into this, do let me know

Answer (score 1):

Misplacedme's answer worked for me, but I don't have enough rep yet, so I'll reply and add some info.

Chrome: Use an Incognito Window (ctrl+shift+N)

Opera: Use a New Private Window (ctrl+shift+N)

IE: No need for special window. It works as it used to.

Firefox: No need for special window. It works as it used to.

Safari:  No need for special window. It works as it used to.

Note: These are all on a Windows 8 PC (sorry, I know most people in their right mind aren't using win8 much less developers)

Comment: oh well, I am using Windows 7 right now...and I am a developer..don't hate but it's mostly for a lack of choice :\